# How to find the orbit of a moving point object given 3 past passing positions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astronomy, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

How do I find the orbit of a moving point object given 3 past passing positions and the tangents at these passing positions, and given that the orbit is known to be an ellipse?

Comment: In an observational situation you generally do not have the tangents, nor full three dimensional data on the positions. Instead you have two angular degrees of freedom and a time hash for each observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2D/3D cases the ellipse has 5/7 degrees of freedom.
You say you have 3 points and their "tangents". A single 2D/3D point gives 3/5 equations. 3 points give 9/15 equations.

So that in both 2D and 3D cases you have an overdetermined equation system (actually it's overdetermined even with 2 points).

In the general case it may be solved for instance by [one of those methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares).

Comment: Although I do not fully understand "freedom", for 2D case , are 3 positions and 2 tangents enough and non overloaded?

Comment: Suggestion to the answer(v1): Replace the word _overloaded_ with _overdetermined._

Comment: Sorry , I must have read your answer . Forget the previous my comment.

Comment: I think that when counting degrees of freedom you should include the time dimension.

Comment: @dmckee: we reduced our problem to finding the ellipse only, regardless to the actual moving body kinematics. Hence - the "time dimension" does not play role here